# datepicker text value is appearing even after clearing ng-model in controller angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datepicker

I`m using a datepicker plugin to select from date and todate selection. After submitting form, I would like to clear textbox values.

So I have cleared textbox ng-model values and is successfully getting cleared in ng-model. But the value is still appearing in textbox value. Tried debugging where the data is getting stored in datepicker.js file I have used. But not luck.

Can you please help me. plese find plnkr link below`enter code here`

[enter link description here](https://plnkr.co/edit/j6m8LR6p3AhkPooyFYhv?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the the issue directly in datepicker.js, Instead of clearing the data, on clearing model, i`m passing 00/00/0000 date in datepicker trigger. see my updated plunker.

```
enter code here
```

[plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/jcKZTMrNqTp6CIZ06Xho?p=preview)